# Content Database Backup

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

For a Content DB backup (part of 2010 DB migration process), how do I set the SharePoint 2007 content DB to "read only" for the duration of the backup?

Comment: Is there any reason a SharePoint database would require anything above and beyond the normal `ALTER DATABASE ... SET READ_ONLY;` command you'd issue for a non-SharePoint database?

Comment: Not that I can think of... what's the reverse of this and can I use the SSMS GUI instead - post your response as an answer? :)

Comment: Why would you want to do this with the GUI?

Comment: I don't think it is. The only thing you have to remember here is that READ_ONLY has an underscore between it and READ_WRITE is the reverse. The UI is a lot more work IMHO. Plus, you can't save your pointing and clicking in a UI to source control, or generate a script for someone else to run, or even just save a history of what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a query window you would:

```
ALTER DATABASE <dbname> SET READ_ONLY;
```

And to revert:

```
ALTER DATABASE <dbname> SET READ_WRITE;
```

If you really want to do this with the GUI, right-click the database, select properties, move to the Options tab, and scroll down to the State section. There you can select `Database Read-Only` and set that to True or False.

Comment: Would I achieve the same thing with: stsadm -o setsitelock -url http://source -lock readonly

Comment: No idea, sorry. I have no idea what stsadm is. But I do find it peculiar that you originally wanted to use SSMS because it would be easier to remember, and are now seeking a comment-line that is quite arguably more difficult to use and remember...

Comment: I'm more familiar with STSADM SHarePoint command line (soon to be deprecated for Powershell)